# Post processing SPH simulation

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I’m very new to blender. I just ran a (sph) fluid simulation and want to post-process it in blender to make it look like this:

[image]

Does anyone have any information which would help me do this? I used splishsplash:

https://github.com/InteractiveComputerGraphics/SPlisHSPlasH

to run the simulation. A related project called splashsurf:

https://github.com/InteractiveComputerGraphics/splashsurf

allows you to extract the surface of the fluid from an sph simulation. In the splashsurf readme it is said that
“These surface meshes can then be fed into 3D rendering software such as Blender to generate beautiful water animations.”
I could not find any more detail as to how this is accomplished. Thus I am here looking for any advice I can get. Anything to point me in the right direction for learning resources is appreciated. If you need any more info such as the file type(s) produced by splashsurf (which btw is either a series of obj or vtk files) just comment and I’ll edit the question.

Comment: I figured it out. In order to import the series of obj or vtk files into blender you can use https://github.com/InteractiveComputerGraphics/blender-sequence-loader which is developed by the same people who made splashsurf and splishsplash. Once the sequence is imported you can render as usual (I’m assuming, I haven’t actually rendered yet).